# Class Depend On Other

Tags: css

I Have A Css Property Called

```
.Zero
{
width:100px;
}
```

I Have Another One Called

```
.One
```

I Need The Class One To Be The Same Class ( Zero ) + 10 px For Example

If Class Zero = 500

Class One = 510

How Can I Do This ?

Answer (score 1):

As per i understand write like this:

```
.Zero,.One
 {
 width:100px;
 }
.One{
 padding-right:10px;
}
```

You can use javascript also. write like this:

```
var modWidth = $('.Zero').width();
$('.one').css({width: modWidth + 10});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/mweEh/

Comment: I think he wants to fill the 10 additional pixels with content. So, this doesn't work.

Comment: I Know This You Here Made The 2 Classes The Same Width But I Need Another One Bigger Than The First Coz Of The Margin Make It Bigger

Comment: @sandeep Now it is fine. I think you should specify that you are using jQuery (I guess). You should also remove the CSS definition above as it doesn't suit Osama question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to do that with CSS alone. You should use javascript+css to do that.

Comment: Ok Could You Give Me The Way Plz

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible with only css but you can use [SCSS -  http://sass-lang.com/](http://sass-lang.com/)

It will allow you to assign a variable and the use as

```
$width: 500;

.Zero{
  width: $width;
}

.one{
  width: $width + 10;
}
```